# Progress 4gl, Openedge Update Progress.ini in all users

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Good day.. I made a change with the progress.ini(change font.size,color etc) in the server.. Do we have a tool in progress that will automatically update their progress.ini and translate them using ini2reg.exe? Or any other alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

The settings are kept **either** in a .ini-file or in the registry. If you're not stating anything in the application startup it will look in the registry.

Migrating changes to clients is something that could be done in a login-script on your Windows domain or similar. Another approach is to use a central shared .ini-filed located on a network drive accessible to all clients.